# What cursors are available through Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor?

Tags: java, awt, mouse-cursor

`java.awt.Cursor` has a method [`getSystemCustomCursor(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getSystemCustomCursor-java.lang.String-).

The documentation there gives only one example of a name: "Invalid.16x16". That doesn't seem to work, but "Invalid.32x32" does. Through googling, I've found one other example of a useful working name: "MoveDrop.32x32".

This method seems like it could be useful. For example, there is no predefined "working in background" (mixed arrow/hourglass) cursor but perhaps it's available through this method.

What cursor names are available, or how can I enumerate them on a particular system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `cursors.properties` files that defines custom system cursors. It resides in `<path_to_jre>\lib\images\cursors` folder. For example there is a definition of `MoveDrop.32x32`:

```
Cursor.MoveDrop.32x32.File=win32_MoveDrop32x32.gif
Cursor.MoveDrop.32x32.HotSpot=0,0
Cursor.MoveDrop.32x32.Name=MoveDrop32x32
```

See [Custom Cursor Shapes](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21126&seqNum=3) article for a custom cursor definition example.

Not sure there is a way to query this file for predefined system cursors. So this method may not be very useful in certain scenarios.

See [Toolkit.createCustomCursor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29) for a simpler way to create a custom cursor. Or you can use [Cursor.getPredefinedCursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getPredefinedCursor%28int%29) to get predefined cursors.