# Setting Cursor In Java

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt, cursors

I've been trying to work out the Windows Cursors. I've successfully matched the Registry values to the names given to the various cursor types in the Mouse Properties dialog (the one accessed via the Control Panel).

For example, what the Registry calls the 'AppStarting' cursor, the Mouse Properties dialog calls the 'Working In Background' cursor, and so on.

Where I'm having trouble is using Java to set those cursors, because for many of them there doesn't appear to be a constant. In Cursor.java the various cursors are defined:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_CURSOR = 0;
public static final int CROSSHAIR_CURSOR = 1;
public static final int TEXT_CURSOR = 2;
public static final int WAIT_CURSOR = 3;
public static final int SW_RESIZE_CURSOR = 4;
public static final int SE_RESIZE_CURSOR = 5;
public static final int NW_RESIZE_CURSOR = 6;
public static final int NE_RESIZE_CURSOR = 7;
public static final int N_RESIZE_CURSOR = 8;
public static final int S_RESIZE_CURSOR = 9;
public static final int W_RESIZE_CURSOR = 10;
public static final int E_RESIZE_CURSOR = 11;
public static final int HAND_CURSOR = 12;
public static final int MOVE_CURSOR = 13;
```

But, after some testing, there are several registry values to which none of them correspond. For example, the registry 'App Starting', 'Help', 'No', 'NWPen', 'Person', 'Pin' and 'UpArrow' entries have no corresponding definition (and they're not just the ints after 13; I got a violation when I used 14 as the value).

More surprisingly, the registry 'Hand' value doesn't actually correspond to the HAND_CURSOR value. Setting a new cursor for the HAND_CURSOR definition doesn't change the value stored in the registry for the 'Hand' key.

So how do I set, say, the AppStarting cursor value using Java?

Info:
Windows 10 64-bit
jdk1.8.0_151

Comment: Java works with a predefined set of platform independed cursors. If you want you can create your own cursor for an image like it shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274606/how-to-change-cursor-icon-in-java).

Comment: The problem is that that doesn't work with an .ani or .cur file - just .gifs and .pngs.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415175/8160553) that says:

> The Java Runtime Environment requires that custom cursors are in PNG or GIF format. Just because you are using Java on a Windows system does not mean that you can use that format for a GUI in Swing/AWT.

However, I was able to find [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getSystemCustomCursor(java.lang.String)) in the documentation, so *maybe* you'll be able to pull the specific cursor you'll looking for by it's name. From that documentation:

> Returns a system-specific custom cursor object matching the specified name. Cursor names are, for example: "Invalid.16x16"

Edit: The second part is not for pulling from the system, rather, the cursors included with the JRE. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24233542/8160553).

Edit 2: I found [this package](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdraw2d%2FCursors.html) that has *an* AppStarting cursor that may fit your needs... If you include the package. Since it's a Cursor object it should serve your purpose.

Edit 3: Information about draw2d on eclipse.org can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/).